# In akka, what's correct pattern to use one (and only one) actor that's not a child?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have 2 actors :

```
class ActorA extends Actor {
   def receive = ???
}

object ActorA {
   val actorA = system.actorOf(Props[ActorA])
}

class ActorB extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case aMessage => ActorA.actorA ! aMessage
  }
}
```

I want the actorA to have at any time only one instance (to apply a kind of back pressure)

But with the code above, if there's an error in the ActorA actor, the actor is restarted and the ActorRef actorA is no longer correct.

What's the correct pattern to use in this case ? Must I use ActorSelection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. `.actorOf()` **creates** an actor

Assuming your two actors are created once in an init Class/Object/Main

```
val actorA = system.actorOf(Props[ActorA])
val actorB = system.actorOf(Props[ActorB])
```

Recover the reference to the existing `ActorA` from the `context`

```
class ActorB extends Actor {

  val aA =  context.actorSelection( "/user/ActorA" )

  def receive = {
    case aMessage => aA ! aMessage
  }
}
```

Alternatives are

- pass ActorA `ActorPath` or its reference to the constructor of ActorB
- create ActorA as a child of ActorB (if that makes sense in your case)

Answer (score 0):

Basically it seems you want a singleton in a distributed system.
Firstly I'd like to highlight that this can get you in trouble if you don't handle partitions very well. Secondly, if you're only on 1 node, than that's not a problem. And lastly, this is implemented as Akka's built-in [cluster-singleton](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-singleton.html), so you can give it a look.